# How to show all categories without data for categories in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, bar-chart, ssrs-2012, stacked-chart

I have a stacked bar report in SSRS.

And my "category group" = "LINE" and I have 6 line (LINE1, LINE2, LINE3, LINE4, LINE5, LINE6)

My vertical axis only shows if I have data for that line. But, I want to show all line on vertical axis without data for that line.

How to do like this?

Comment: For this you need to modify your query. You need all categories as a source to be `LEFT JOINED` with your data set. In case there's no data, you will still get a `null` or `0` value, depending on how you will handle nulls.